# Google Analytics Funnel Visualization Not Reporting Magento OnePage Checkout Process Correctly

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I'm running a Magento website which uses the OnePage checkout method. I've added the following script to /app/design/frontend/< my site >/template/checkout/onepage.phtml:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function(section) {
try {
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'checkout/onepage/' + section]);
} catch(err) { }
section = $('opc-'+section);
section.addClassName('allow');
this.accordion.openSection(section);
};
</script>
```

and I've set up within Google Analytics a goal which does the following:-

```
Goal URL: /checkout/onepage/success/
Match Type: Head Match
Step 1: /checkout/cart/ - Cart
Step 2: /checkout/onepage/ - Login or Register
Step 3: /checkout/onepage/billing - Billing Address
Step 4: /checkout/onepage/shipping - Shipping Address
Step 5: /checkout/onepage/shipping_method/ - Shipping Method
Step 6: /checkout/onepage/payment/ - Payment Details
Step 7: /checkout/onepage/review/ - Review
```

The issue I'm having is that whilst goal conversions are being correctly reported I receive incorrect reporting results via the funnel visualization such as /checkout/onepage/billing appearing at the Login or Register stage which means I'm losing data after this stage as to where people have exited. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is my current setup that work without any issues

[image]

Comment: An addition to the above which was a good start for my site analytics. Try deleting `/checkout/cart/` and reentering it. As you enter the URI string, Google Analytics may pop up a suggestion like `/checkout/cart/index.php`. Select that and use it. If it's using `index.php` on one, it will want it on the rest including the goal URL. Despite the fact that `index.php` doesn't show in the cart due to URL rewrites, Google may be detecting it anyway. Once I took care of that, everything snapped into place with inflows and outflows showing properly.

Comment: Many thanks for your input on this. I shall give these methods a try and will let you know the outcome :o)